Display multiple data on multiple Larapex Charts
I'm working on a laravel dashboard that needs to display several charts at once. I'm using Larapex Charts to display those charts. Everything was going well until I had to display more than one data in a chart like the following
public function index(
        FcrChart $fcrChart,
        ProduksiChart $produksiChart,
        KandangChart $kandangChart
    ) {
 return view('dashboard.index', [
                    'title' => 'Dashboard',
                    'harians' => AyamHarian::latest()->paginate('10'),
                    'fcrChart' => $fcrChart->build(),
                    'produksiChart' => $produksiChart->build(),
                    'kandangChart' => $kandangChart->build()
                ]);
}

This is the line of code that serves to retrieve and return data to be displayed in the Larapex Chart
public function build(): \ArielMejiaDev\LarapexCharts\LineChart
    {
        $year = date("Y");
        $month = date("m");

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $month; $i++) {
            $avgProduction = AyamHarian::whereYear('tanggal', $year)
                ->whereMonth('tanggal', $i)
                ->avg('produktifitas');
            $roundedValue = round($avgProduction, 3);
            $months[] = Carbon::create()->month($i)->format("F");
            $avgData[] = $roundedValue;
        }

        return $this->chart->lineChart()
            ->setTitle('Produksi Bulanan')
            ->setSubtitle('Tahun ' . date("Y"))
            ->addData('Rata-rata Produktivitas', $avgData)
            ->setHeight(430)
            ->setXAxis($months);
    }

If I add one more addData() in the return statement
return $this->chart->lineChart()
            ->setTitle('Produksi Bulanan')
            ->setSubtitle('Tahun ' . date("Y"))
            ->addData('Rata-rata Produktivitas', $avgData)
            ->addData('Fake Data', [10.34, 20.45, 30.23, 32.54, 43.30, 12.30, 23.37, 37.34, 60.25, 34.25, 23.33])
            ->setHeight(430)
            ->setXAxis($months);

The chart become like this Image after I add one more addData()
As you can see from the image I provided, the other graphs are fine. But the chart with the title Produksi Bulanan becomes a mere dot.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Check $months Count: Ensure the $months array has the correct number of elements. If the X-axis has, for example, 12 months, all data series added with addData must also have exactly 12 values.

Thanks for the help  But unfortunately it didn't work. In the end I added two charts separately.
